# Serial Communication in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am new with vb6 and communication app, I try to run a example that transmitting  and receiving data between two serial ports ( I install two serial ports by **com0com** soft).

In this example, I want User to type charracters in textbox1, then click command button, and charracters in textbox1 display in textbox2.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
com1.Output = Text1.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
com1.CommPort = 1
com1.Settings = "9600,n,8,1"
com1.PortOpen = True
com2.CommPort = 2
com2.Settings = "9600,n,8,1"
com2.PortOpen = True

Text1.Text = ""
Text2.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub com2_OnComm()
If com2.CommEvent = comEvReceive Then
    Text2.Text = Text2.Text + com2.Input

End If
End Sub
```

I screened `form` in the example and setting in com0com port, I don't have enought reputation to post image, so I upload this to flickr.

http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7627/16740707238_6b1d9ec3ab_b.jpg

But when I try to run this example by type charracters in textbox1 and click button, nothing happen.

So what am I doing wrong?. If so, how can I do to get data from com1 port to com2port? Or any advice for anything!

thanks for reading !

Comment: Are you sure the cable is correct?

Comment: Is there a cable?  I thought he was using a device driver that implements two ports looped back to back.

Comment: Yes, I was using software to implement two serial port.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look a little harder at the documentation.

Here's a minimal example where COM3/COM4 are the looped ports on my machine:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If Len(Text1.Text) > 0 Then
        MSComm1.Output = Text1.Text
        Text1.Text = vbNullString
    End If
    Text1.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    With MSComm1
        .CommPort = 3
        .Settings = "256000,n,8,1"
        .Handshaking = comNone
        .SThreshold = 0 'No events after send completions.
        .RThreshold = 0 'No events after receive completions.
        .PortOpen = True
    End With
    With MSComm2
        .CommPort = 4
        .Settings = "256000,n,8,1"
        .EOFEnable = False
        .Handshaking = comNone
        .InputMode = comInputModeText
        .RThreshold = 1 'Event for each character received.  Terribly
                        'inefficient but if char-by-char events are
                        'required there isn't much choice.
        .SThreshold = 0 'No events after send completions.
        .PortOpen = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    MSComm1.PortOpen = False
    MSComm2.PortOpen = False
End Sub

Private Sub MSComm2_OnComm()
    With MSComm2
        If .CommEvent = comEvReceive Then
            .InputLen = 0
            Text2.SelStart = &H7FFF
            Text2.SelText = .Input
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, Your code helped me a lot, I get exactly what I want.